# How to convert vtk data in a way that to handle with opengl

Tags: opengl, vtk

I am trying to use (with some other types) also vtk in my back end of the program. However, I want to visualize it in a third party opengl renderer code(magnumgraphics). Therefore I don't want to use any rendering related to vtk(or paraview).

does anyone has an idea of how can i extract the data in a way that i can use it with opengl.

in my vtk structure (vtkUnstructuredGrid) there are vorticity field, points and more. the question in short is to how to derive these values as separate arrays to treat differently.

Regards,

Comment: OpenGL data, image or vector, needs to be in C (or FORTRAN) fixed layout arrays. That is, you give OpenGL a pointer to a block of memory and tell it how many floats (or ints) to read.
Since VTK is written in C++, the underlying data structures will almost certainly be fixed layout arrays as well. If there is an API in VTK to get a pointer to the raw data, or copy into your own block of memory, that should do.
Hope this helps

Comment: No, that would work for triangles. The point of an unstructured grid is that it contains mixed data so the point of the question is how to split the different types of data (vectors, points, etc) to display each type differently in OpenGL.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: Its been quite some while and I do not use vtk no more. maybe you can check [here](https://github.com/sariug/mpfluid_cave_frontend/blob/63f1624d4c92613dac3e531ca90966c3c6355e5b/include/vtkProcessor.h#L232) maybe this would somehow help at least @user42